# 4 part counterpoint to chordal harmony transition

Tags: theory, counterpoint, transition

In one of my first solo piano pieces(a Rondo)the A theme is stated, ending on a Picardy third to transition to the second, B theme in the parallel major, which starts in a 4 part counterpoint, and soon transitions to what can only be described as an irregularly syncopated waltz, with a fully waltz-like lower section. Both of these sections are doing well on their own, the problem is connecting them. I want their transition to be nearly completely seamless, without the shock of a Picardy third only about 15 seconds before. But the transition between these always feels like everything instantly slowed down to the waltz-like section, rather than a seamless, barely noticeable transition I am aiming for. How do you transition between sections of a theme such as these?

P.S. Sometimes, yes, what I described(instantly slowing down) can work, but in this case, it most definitely does not. I tried it many times and had it reviewed by a friend, and we both agreed it does not work.

Comment: Hi Gregory. Welcome to the site. Your question doesn't fit the model here, but it fits perfectly in [our chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/440/the-practice-room). Once your reputation score is >=20 you can post there. I suggest including the score — at least the parts on either side of the transition.

Comment: I upvoted to get you to 20 reputation.

Comment: Is the waltz-like section in a different meter from the earlier portions of the piece? Or a different tempo? *Or both?* Both of these may provide insurmountable obstacles when trying to compose a smooth transition tempo-wise.

Comment: By the way, there could be some good on-topic questions that could derive from this one, something like "How can I make the transition between tempos (or meters) smoother," or "How can I smoothly resume a minor mode after a Picardy cadence"?, preferably with lots of detail and posting the actual music.